# "Module rtl8192ce not found" - Howto reinstall Ubuntu's realtek driver? (on12.04)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, realtek, rtl8192ce

On trying to get my RTL8188CE wireless card to work reliably, I tried installing the rtl8192ce driver directly from [realtek's website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CE). However, now I got a kernel panic everytime I tried to load the driver. I was able to remove it again in safemode using realtek's `make uninstall` script. Now there is no driver for my card at all and it doesn't show up in network-manager any more. When I try to manually load the rtl8192ce module I get:

```
FATAL: Module rtl8192ce not found.
```

So how can I reinstall the original Ubuntu rtl8192ce driver so I have at least some connectivity?

Comment: It is really painfull if you have that wifi module. I have it to with the driver succesfully installed. But can only acces wifi 2 meter from the router. I would suggest just buy a powerline adapter and take the cable ;).

Comment: I guess you're right, Thomas. I wish I had known that before I bought the card. :( I ordered an Intel Centrino Card which is Ubuntu Certified and will replace the Realtek one. Should have done that in the first place. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an updated version by doing, with a temporary ethernet connection:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You pointed me into the right direction! I was running the 3.5 kernel from the Hardware Enablement Stack, so I reinstalled that, which gave me back the rtl8192ce module. It complained about missing firmware though. I had to copy the realtek firmware back to /lib/firmware/rtlwifi (aparently the realtek uninstall script deleted the entire directory) and now I am back with the half working wireless connection I started out with.